# iowait monitoring in top on OSX/iMac

Tags: osx, io, top, macintosh, bsd

I'm trying to monitor the performance of a process on OSX 10 (iMac), specifically whether I/O is currently a bottleneck or not. I don't use the machine, hence I need something simple that the user can run and report me about.

I found `top` very confusing on the OSX terminal: unless I'm blind, there are no IO statistics at all. What's the *easiest* built-in command to get the current CPU iowait of the machine?

Comment: Hm. `top -m io` perhaps? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=top&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html Assuming it's really a BSD top.

Comment: Why not have them run the Activity Monitor?

Comment: @thrig Hm, good point. I didn't know about it and I prefer to teach things that can be used in other OS too. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464#disk doesn't mention iowait at all, I only see total disk activity of each process and current combined disk activity. Speed of disks can vary wildly, so those numbers don't help much. Is there something simple which can tell me whether a process is currently CPU-bound or disk-bound?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? - I too am looking for specifically IO wait, to see how long the CPU is waiting for a drive to respond.

Comment: @RomanGaufman not really. I think I ended up asking the user to install `atop` with homebrew, or something like that.

Comment: Says atop is not supported on mac, only linux :(

Comment: A related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786618/per-process-disk-read-write-statistics-in-mac-os-x where people point out that you used to be able to use iotop or similar, but since MacOS 10.11 (2015) there are increasing restrictions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616033/1333493